unable to run ufw on Ubuntu
This is the error message I am getting Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded
I have tried the following
sudo apt-get install --reinstall iptables
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-modules-5.4.0-42-generic

The second one give me this error message Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-modules-5.4.0-42-generic
So I guess I am missing something, anybody has an idea what I might be missing?
I am using Ubuntu 24, and I am trying to access my VPS via SSH to setup wireguard client to import the configuration to my router, and I am getting permission denied, publickey, password.
But in order to access the VPS via SSH the firewall must be running if I am not wrong.

so, Ubuntu 24.04 doesn't have that kernel version in it.  Additionally, what is the VPS backend?  If it's not KVM then it might not have the ability to alter kernel modules.

I was able to put the ufw running, but I am still unable to access the vps via ssh on Ubuntu, I am getting the same error, Permission denied, publickey, password.

I checked the VPS backend and it is disabled, should it be enabled to access it via SSH? The firewall is already running but I cannot connect via ssh still

The errors being received suggest your password or username are wrong. What user are you trying to SSH into?

I am using my VPS password, and root as the username.
The problem is I cannot see what I am typing when the password is prompted, but I am sure I am using the right one because I can access the VPS through the remote desktop app on Windows 10 pro.
Any suggestion? I have never ben able to access via SSH to my server, and it has been almost a month.

RDP and SSH are independently different systems. By default, PermitRootLogin is set to without-password or no in SSH. If you have access to the console on the VPS panel, and can check /etc/ssh/sshd_config and see if PermitRootLogin is set to no or without-password that'd be great.  Note that it is not secure to SSH as root with a password because of password bruteforcing that happens to SSH servers.

The PermitRootLogin is set to yes. I have also tried to access the VPS via SSH using publickey but when I set PermitRootLogin without-password, the Ubuntu is still asking me for the password.

The reason why I am trying to access the VPS via SSH is to be able to setup wireguard client and import the configuration to my router, so I can use the VPS connection in the router without needing to access the VPS via remote desktop app on my Windows.
